# SSL using Security Framework on iOS

Tags: ios, security, ssl, frameworks, https

I know that we can make requests to `https://` through iOS Security Framework or with NSURL. even though the server wont provide us a valid certificate.

One consequence for such type of communication is **Man in the middle attack**.

Can some one explain how often this is used and what other problems it might have.

Comment: By default, NSURLRequest will abort any HTTPS connection with an invalid certificate. Please further explain your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MITM attacks aren't all that common, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't be concerned about them.  If you don't verify the identify of the server (meaning checking the validity of the certificate against a trusted third party), your users could fall victim.

What is becoming quite common these days is people accessing services from work (such as web email), and having the company proxy sniff and record their traffic by essentially performing a MITM attack.

I know it's a pain, but it is very important that you enforce the identity of the server in order to provide the expected security of https.  If you can't, you should alert the user to that in some manner so that they know the security risks and can proceed if they want to.  If you've ever gotten the "Get Me Out Of Here!" screen from Firefox, this is exactly what FF is doing.